# Using %* as string parameter on windows .bat files

Tags: batch-file, parameters, command-prompt

I've been trying to create a simple .bat file to run google search via terminal, but i've found a problem with my parameters(?), i've been searching for some answers and found many possible ways to accomplish what i was trying to achieve, yet none of them worked so either something is wrong within my code or im just dumb enough to program in this thing D:

anyway.. here goes my .bat versions and the problems i've faced within my tries

**V-1.0**

First try was like this :

Problem :: Can't use the command without "somethingToSearch" 
and the search includes "somethingToSearch"

Example :: google "minna esper da yo"

would result in googling "mina esper da yo" with the "" 
which limits the content of the search to some point. .. and its hella boring to type those on my keyboard

**google.bat 1.0**

```
@echo off
start http:\\google.com\search?q=%1
```

**V-2.0**

Tried to change "%1" to "%*" to get all %parameters% and set a stringVar = %parameters% ... could not find a way to do that....
i've tried

> for /F %%a in (%input%) do set search=%%a

which gives ::  ECHO search = %1 (always)

**V-3.0**

seeing my inability to parse "%*" i've decided to remove the "" from the %1 parameter and set it into search ... couldn't find anything useful besides %~1 which expands the string (.. this is half-way? i believe) but i couldn't set a variable equal += expansions ? *im dumb i know

**TL;DR**

So my question : is is there a way to transform all parameters (%*)  into one single string without the quotation mark?

which would imply::

is there a way to get this to work?

> google minna esper da yo

input = minna esper da yo

%1 = minna

%2 = esper

etc

so the .bat would do ::  search?q=%1+%2+%3....%n

note :: i have no idea how many parameters i'd search? i think i could make a boundary and create a for loop to iterate and check if %1-9 exist? and add into search, but i'll do that only if i don't really find any solution....

thanks for reading and sorry for troubling you guys <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
set googleq=%*
start http://google.com/?#q=%googleq: =+%
```

Comment: oh, that's amazing you've done it so simple .. i actually found a way to do it myself later on that night using a loop .. but your way is so simple =]
i don't really understand much about .bat scripting so i have no idea what you did, if its not trouble, mind explaning what : =+% does?

Comment: It does a string replace, swapping empty spaces for + characters. You can read more at http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntset.php in the 'String Substitution' section. That only works for environment variables, which is why I use `set` to put the parameters into an environment variable, then get them out again right away including swapping space for plus.